# How to make pivoting arms move symmetrically towards each other?

Tags: applied-mechanics, pulleys

I have a basic design of two arms which need to be brought together. But I tried the design using a test setup and it did not work successfully. Here is a diagram of my design - 
[image]

What I observed is that arm 2 moves up before arm 1. I want both of them to move towards each other to cause a compression, and away from each other to cause expansion. Is there any way in which that could be achieved using minimal design requirements?

Comment: Have the arms connected with gears at their pivot.

Comment: @SolarMike: That's the same solution I was thinking of.  Even if short and sweet it belongs in an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two options:

1) have the arms connected by gears at the pivot point - when one is moved so will the other, in fact one could be fixed...

2) connect the arms with a threaded rod (needs left & right hand threads) and use a pulley to rotate the rod - then the arms will move according to the  pitch of the thread - actually 1 turn will move twice the pitch.

Comment: in both these cases, how will the rotation in any one direction, cause the arms to move in opposite directions? Could you explain that? Thanks

Comment: Think of a pair of calipers, some have a threaded rod (with left & right hand threads) which means they open and close with rotation of the rod. With gears if one move then the other moves...

Comment: Thanks a lot! Makes sense, but just be sure, it will cause both the arms to move right? I.e  none of the arms are stationary, because I want it to compress a material kept in the middle equally on both the opposite faces.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ideas which have worked for different gears

like this drafting compass with a threaded shaft and a roller:

[image: drafting compas]

And this pantograph.

.

[image: pantograph]

-

Answer (score 0):

You could try 2 bar linkages, it's basically what you're already trying but without a pulley and unequal displacement.